# Help me! I switched to code on the left and now I can't get it back to text. I'm a newbie so I have no idea,

Tags: code, text

I cannot get the left side into alphabetic text.

Comment: Welcome to TeX SX! What are you talking of?

Comment: If this is a problem of an editor, please tell us which one.